# replot within function gnuplot

Tags: c++, gnuplot

Please excuse newbie question - haven't been able to find anything helpful online.

I currently have a motion capture system set up to stream data to my computer. I have a function (C++) that is triggered every time I receive a frame and it currently writes this data to a file. What I would like is for the points to also be plotted (i.e. the plot refreshed) every time there is a frame. The problem I am having is that since the frame triggers a function, I can't seem to get gnuplot to not open a new window for each plot.

I am using gnuplot-iostream. Currently I have the following code

```
void printRigidBodies(Mocha::Frame::KPtr frame) // This function is triggered every time a new frame is received
{
  Gnuplot gp;
  std::ofstream dat;
  dat.open ("Optitrack_data.dat");

  for(auto& name: frame->listRigidBodiesNames()) //For loop over all the bodies contained in the frame
    {

    //... 

    gp << "set title  'Optitrack streaming data' \n";
    gp << "set xrange [-2000:2000]\nset yrange [-2000:2000]\nset zrange [0:2000]\n";
    gp << "splot 'Optitrack_data.dat'u 1:2:3 with points notitle" << std::endl;
    dat.close();
    }
}
```

I have tried:

1. using "set multiplot"
2. having a first 'splot' in my 'main' function before the 'printRigidBodies' function is triggered and changing the line within the function to 'replot'
3. similarly using 'reread' and
4. trying to define where gnuplot should output the file.

I believe the problem is that Gnuplot effectively resets all commands when the function is called each time.

Any help appreciated and as I said I'm quite new to this so its very possible I'm using this in the wrong way!